# Strange error when setting values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

This loop is working to change other columns in my DataFrame. But I keep running into this error on this specific column/dataframe. I'm basically trying do in a VLOOKUP between tables in Pandas.

> KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

This code is working fine with no errors. It returns the appropiate value to the "Adjusted Agency" column

```
for i in range(len(df_ult_cust)):

    df.loc[df.Ult_Cust == df_ult_cust['Ult_Cust'].iloc[i], 'Adjusted Agency'] = df_ult_cust['ACRONYM'].iloc[i]
```

But when I use this block of code, I get that strange key error listed above.

```
for j in range(len(df_pca_cust)):

    df.loc[df.div == df_pca_cust['pca'].iloc[j], 'Division'] = df_pca_cust['div_acronym'].iloc[j]
```

Note: I chose not to use the itterows Pandas function here as for some reason it was causing the code to run slower.

Comment: If you are essentially trying to do a vlookup just use `merge` [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: if `div` is meant to be a column in your DataFrame, maybe there's an issue with a clash with the DataFrame method `df.div()`. more broadly, i avoid using "dot" access to columns due to potential problems such as this.

Comment: That's a great point `df['div']` may work. @mechanical_meat

Comment: @mechanical_meat you were right! That was the problem. Thank you so much for your help. Thank you too Henry Ecker and It_is_Chris